# CodedUI test does not read data from CSV input file

Tags: csv, visual-studio-2013, import, coded-ui-tests, data-driven-tests

I am having difficulty mapping a CSV file with the Coded UI test method. This is most likely a stupid question but I cannot seem to find a solution for my problem, at least not one that works. I have made sure to set the property of the CSV file to **Copy always**.
I have also imported the CSV file by writing the following line above the test method.

```
[DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.CSV", "|DataDirectory|\\Data\\login.csv", "login#csv", DataAccessMethod.Sequential), DeploymentItem("login.csv"), TestMethod]
```

The file name is `login.csv` and it resides in the `Data` folder.

The test will compile without any problem but once the test executes the fields that should receive input from the CSV file are left empty and the execution is interrupted. I've tried replacing the data from the CSV file by using Strings and it works perfectly fine. The piece of code I am using to import each parameter is:

```
TestContext.DataRow["Username"].ToString()
```

Also, the CSV file contains something along the following lines:

```
Username,Password,Fullname
admin@mail.com,password,Admin
```

Is there anyone who can point what it is I am forgetting.

Update: I pinpointed the issue, it seems like the issue only revolves around the first column in the csv file. When I try to import any of the other values it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Are your `.csv` files set as "Content", "Copy Always | Copy if Newer"?

Comment: @jessehouwing - Yes build action is set to Content and the 'copy to output direct' is also set to 'Copy Always'

Comment: Everything seems fine to me. It should work. Let us know if you figure out the issue.

Comment: @SarkarG - Yes I will, I've pinpointed the issue. It seems like it's only when I try to get the first element from the csv file. So If I ignore the first column of the csv file the test runs perfectly fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some text files start with a Byte Order Mark (BOM). The CSV reader within Coded UI does not handle the BOM and treats it as part of the first field name. The screen shot below shows the debug trace of a CSV file with a BOM and that same file shown in Notepad++. The `DataRow.ItemArray[...]` values are as expected. The `DataRow.Table.Columns.ResultsView[...]` shows the field names, but the first field name includes the BOM.

This CSV file with a BOM was created in Visual Studio using Solution Explorer => Add => New item => C# => General => Text file. Previously I have created a spread sheet with Microsoft Excel and saved it as a CSV file, that file did not have a BOM. I have also created files with Notepad++ and saved as CSV and they did not have a BOM. It appears that Visual Studio creates files with a BOM but when editing CSV files it does not add a BOM.

[image]

---

Visual Studio can create files with the correct encoding. Within "**Step 2 - Create a data set**" of [this Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee624082(v=vs.120).aspx) page it states the text below. (Thanks also to **Holistic Developer** for providing very similar details in a comment.):

> 3. It is important to save the .csv file using the correct encoding. On the FILE menu, choose Advanced Save Options and choose Unicode
>      (UTF-8 without signature) – Codepage 65001 as the encoding.

Comment: @AdrianHHH I ended up testing this question with csv created with Excel and notepad only. Never thought visual studio will be the culprit.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2013, you can choose File > Advanced Save Options and select an encoding without a BOM. For example, choose either `Unicode (UTF-8 without signature) - Codepage 65001` for a unicode file or `Western European (Windows) - Codepage 1252` for an ANSI file.

Answer (score 1):

For Visaul Studio 2010, i could solve issue be selecting "Western European (Windows) - Codepage 1252" encoding for CSV files.

Summary of steps:
In visual studio 2010, Open CSV file > Go to File menu > Select " Advanced Save Options" > Select "Western European (Windows) - Codepage 1252" > Save.

This should help.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best solution but its kind of a workaround. I simply set the first element to something random and since I don't need access to the first element it doesn't matter that I don't have access to it.

If anyone finds a correct way to solve this problem I'd be grateful for your solution.