# strange behavior when running bat file code

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, batch-file, cmd

I'm having a strange problem when running a bat file from c# code(Also from cmd.exe and Run window).
First of all, my bat file looks like this

**file_copy.bat**

`NET USE %1 /USER:%2 %3
COPY /Y %4 %5
NET USE %1 /DELETE
PAUSE`

I've included this bat file in visual studio 2013, and set `Copy To Output Directory` to `Always Copy` from properties. My code to run this bat file looks like this

```
            string args = "\"\\\\192.168.54.196\\c$\" \"user\" \"123456\" \"\\\\192.168.54.196\\c$\\paykiosk\\logs\\pgw_150113.log\" \"C:\\Users\\IlhamIs\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pgw_150113.log\""
            var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                UseShellExecute = false,
                FileName = "file_copy.bat",
                Arguments = args
            };

            var process = new Process { StartInfo = processInfo };
            process.Start();
```

I build my project and obviously file_copy.bat is copied to `bin\debug` directory(in my case). Then I run application, bat file executes, but first command is somehow modified at runtume, therefore an error occurs saying `'я╗┐NET' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`. This is wierd, `я╗┐` is written to the beginning of first command. Here is complete output that I got:

```
C:\Users\IlhamIs\Desktop\test\bin\debug>я╗┐NET USE "\\192.168.54.196\c$" /USER:"user" "123456"
'я╗┐NET' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\IlhamIs\Desktop\test\bin\debug>COPY /Y "\\192.168.54.196\c$\paykiosk\logs\pgw_150113.l
og" "C:\Users\IlhamIs\AppData\Local\Temp\pgw_150113.log"
Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.

C:\Users\IlhamIs\Desktop\test\bin\debug>NET USE "\\192.168.54.196\c$" /DELETE
The network connection could not be found.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2250.


C:\Users\IlhamIs\Desktop\test\bin\debug>PAUSE
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Then create a bat file in `bin\debug` directory with the same script (file_copy_2.bat), note that this is not created by visual studio. This time I change `FileName = "file_copy.bat"` to `FileName = "file_copy_2.bat"` to make my application to run the file I created and then I run my application. It looks ridiculous, but it worked, all 3 commands executed successfully.

This is really strange. **What am I missing? Does visual studio do something special with bat file during compilation and copying file to output directory?** Both `file_copy.bat` and `file_copy_2.bat` are the same (I've checked attributes just in case, also the same). The file visual studio created fails to execute first command, BUT the one I created myself succeeds. Why?

FYI,
Code Page code returned from command chcp is 866. I've tried 65001 which is utf-8, but I've got similar result, different characters written to the beginning of command instead of `я╗┐`

Please comment below if question details aren't clear to you, as I could explain wrong

Thanks in advance

Comment: look at [this](http://superuser.com/questions/113696/strange-symbols-while-executing-win-command-file) question and answer on SuperUser, he has the same problem with the same strange symbols

Comment: That looks like a byte order mark. Use a text editor that can save without a BOM. Like notepad++. Or save as ASCII/ANSI.

Comment: I saved the file without BOM and it worked! Thank you for your assistance, I googled a lot, but didn't find that question posted on SuperUser, spent all day solving this

Comment: See the second paragraph of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24735579/codedui-test-will-not-find-csv-input/24768318#24768318 where I wrote about how Visual Studio creates files with unexpected BOMs. The rest of that Q&A is about BOMs being misinterpreted by another part of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is clearly in your file_copy.bat.
You can proove it, by run the file_copy.bat from command line (with appropriate parameters).

Do you **creating the file_copy**, or copy paste from some location in project?

**Update:**
From comments i understand that. The problem is the encoding of the file_copy.bat.
When converting bat file to the UTF-8 without BOM, the problem is solved.

Comment: as I mentioned in my question, I also tried running this bat file from command line and Run window. And, yes, I'm creating new bat file from scratch. Same results with copy/paste. The problem was in the encoding that I provided, by default it's saved with BOM, I tried saving the file with UTF-8 encoding without BOM and problem solved. Thank you for the answer