# Coded UI: Not able to use CSV file in script in TFS solution explorer while it is working fine on the local machine

Tags: unit-testing, csv, tfs, coded-ui-tests

I have done the below steps, it is working fine on my local machine but when I worked with TFS solution explore below error display (newlines added for clarity):

```
Error: The character encoding for the file D:\Testcase\data.csv has changed.
Your source control provider may have problems managing files with this type of encoding.
For example, if you save an ANSI-encoded file as UTF-8 you may not be able to merge or show differences.
```

Steps:

1. Created data.csv file.
2. Advance save as a unicode (utf-8 without signature Codepage-65001).
3. Make data.csv file as copy if new

Code:

```
[DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.CSV", "|DataDirectory|\\data.csv", "data#csv", DataAccessMethod.Sequential), DeploymentItem("data.csv"), TestMethod]
    public void CodedUITestMethod1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(TestContext.DataRow["firstname"].ToString());
        // To generate code for this test, select "Generate Code for Coded UI Test" from the shortcut menu and select one of the menu items.
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [CodedUI test does not read data from CSV input file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24735579/codedui-test-does-not-read-data-from-csv-input-file)

Answer (score 0):

Set the `Copy to Output Directory` in the properties window for that file to `Copy Always` or `Copy if Newer`.