# Coded UI - Setting text value in a WPF Text box via data source

Tags: wpf, data-binding, coded-ui-tests

This is my first time tangling with Coded UI and I've hit my first real speed bump. I don't have Microsoft Test Manager which may make this process trivial, but I'm having a heck of a time.

I have a text box, let's call it 'Project Name'. I want to run a small test in several iterations, each one using a different Project Name (the static value is set as 'Castle'). I have my CSV file created and my Data Source set, but I cannot find the right syntax to use TestContext to point the variable to the CSV.

Everything I've found says to use some variation of 'SearchProperties[WpfButton.PropertyNames.SOMETHING] = TestContext.DataRow["ProjectName"].ToString();'.

My issue is I can't find anything in PropertyNames that represents the value of the input string, nor does adding 'value' as a property do anything. The only place in the UImap that I can find the static Value set is in the UI actions tree, in the SetValueActionWrapper properties.

How do I specify the right value? The frustrating thing is this is an extremely trivial task in the other automation tools that I've used, but I'm not a strong coder. Please advise!

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this is to let Coded UI teach you how to do it. In a sandbox project use Coded UI to record the required actions then copy the interesting or useful pieces into your own tests. For entering text into a text box you could just record the displaying of the text box and the typing of the text. For much more on how to data drive with Coded UI see [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25742114/546871).

Whilst MTM is a very useful program I believe it would not make the problem you have any easier.

Comment: Thanks for the article, that looks helpful. So if the method that the recorder comes up with is this;

Comment: public void TypeProjectName()
        {
            #region Variable Declarations
            WpfEdit uIItemEdit = this.UIUploadProjectWindow.UIItemEdit;
            #endregion

            // Type 'Castle' in text box
            uIItemEdit.Text = this.TypeProjectNameParams.UIItemEditText;

Comment: I revised the code to 'this.UIMap.UIUploadProjectWindow.UIItemEdit.Text = TestContext.DataRow["ProjectName"].ToString();' where ProjectName is the first column in my CSV. The exception I get is "Column ProjectName does not belong to table ." Is the format of my CSV wrong? There are no spaces, no quotes, just commas.

Comment: The code looks OK, but you have not shown the CSV file (only the top 2 or 3 lines is needed). See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/24768318/546871 about the BOM issue with CSV files.