# How to run web performance test for 200 users in VS 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, automated-tests, performance-testing, load-testing

I am able to run Load test on my website using single login and running 200 concurrent users in VS 2013 ultimate version.

What I would like to do is instead of single login/password, I want to have 200 different login/pass so test can pick up each user randomly and use that login to perform the test. How do I do that?

How do I tell web performance test to use predefined 200 login/pass and use new user for each test it runs simultaneously.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to use a list of values for a parameter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23649732/how-to-use-a-list-of-values-for-a-parameter)

Comment: yup link provided by you has the entire answer I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to add a data source to the webtest, that contains the details of the users.

See [Add a data source to a web performance test](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243142.aspx) for details.