# Load Testing for different users in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, load-testing

I have created a Web and Load test project in Visual Studio 2015. It has a webtest which has recorded steps of a scenario. It contain a form with a username to login (in my case password is not required). I have also added a datasource with 25 user names for the form parameter.
I have added a load test with the above webtest to run it for 25 users in parallel with different usernames. But the load test is running with the same user name. Can any one suggest me, how to configure it for different users.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You need to supply a lot more information to get an answer. If you follow carefully the various Microsoft web pages about data driving it works. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/23673194/546871 .

Comment: The point of load testing is to learn how the system being tested behaves under load. Are you able to [edit] the question to add additional information? Load testing with Visual Studio is a topic with little activity on this site so I think you need to add more details to raise interest on this question